# Single pass lens for the root of a balanced binary tree

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, gadt

I have a balanced binary tree that includes the tree's depth in its type:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
data Tree (n :: Nat) a where
  Leaf :: Tree Zero a
  Branch :: a -> (Tree n a, Tree n a) -> Tree (Succ n) a
```

I'd like a way to run arbitrary functions `f :: Tree n a -> Tree n a` on the subtree of depth `n` at the root of any `Tree m a`, `m` ≥`n`.

I was able to implement this one way using a type class for extracting and replacing the root-subtree:

```
mapRoot :: X m n => (Tree n a -> Tree n a) -> Tree m a -> Tree m a
mapRoot f t = putRoot (f (getRoot t)) t

class X m n where 
  getRoot :: Tree m a -> Tree n a
  putRoot :: Tree n a -> Tree m a -> Tree m a

instance X m Zero where
  getRoot t = Leaf
  putRoot Leaf t = t

instance X m n => X (Succ m) (Succ n) where
  getRoot (Branch a (l,r)) = (Branch a (getRoot l, getRoot r))
  putRoot (Branch a (l,r)) (Branch _ (l',r')) = Branch a (putRoot l l', putRoot r r')
```

While this works, it requires two passes through the root subtree, and I'd like to do it in one, if possible.

This is *almost* possible by using lazy evaluation (tying the knot):

```
mapRoot' :: Y m n => (Tree n a -> Tree n a) -> Tree m a -> Tree m a
mapRoot' f t = t' where
  (r, t') = swapRoot t r'
  r' = f r 

class Y m n where
  swapRoot :: (Tree m a, Tree n a) -> (Tree n a, Tree m a)

instance Y m Zero where 
  swapRoot t leaf = (leaf, t)

instance Y m n => Y (Succ m) (Succ n) where
  swapRoot (Branch a (l,r)) (Branch a' (l',r')) = (Branch a (lx,rx), Branch a' (lx',rx')) where
    (lx,lx') = swapRoot l l'
    (rx,rx') = swapRoot r r'
```

But if you actually try to run `mapRoot'` you'll find that it doesn't halt; this is because `swapRoot` isn't lazy in its second argument (which it can't be, because `Tree n a` is a GADT).

However, given `getRoot` and `putRoot`, I've got *a* lens for the root subtree, which leads me to suspect there's others, including one that can be used to implement `mapRoot` in a single pass.

What is such a lens?

Comment: May I ask why you choose a GADT rather than a nested type here?

Comment: dfeuer: I think I need to make assertions at compile time that are easier with naturals than with nested pairs... but I'll consider it.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood you. When you say "subtree", are you actually talking about the uppermost portion of the tree (i.e., all nodes down to a particular depth)?

Comment: dfeuer: Yes, that's what I tried to specify by "subtree of depth n at the root".

Comment: I've looked at this a bit more and given it some additional thought. My conclusion is that your original two-pass implementation is very likely the best one possible for this exact function, up to a bit of wiggle. The *inherent* difficulty is that you have no information about how `f`s consumption and production rates relate. If `f` were known to be `fmap g` that would be different.

Comment: I'd love to see more information about what you're actually using this tree for, and what sorts of assertions you wish to make about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "tying the knot" approach is sound - you just need all the parameters in the right place so the function can be sufficiently lazy.

```
data (:<=) (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) where 
  LTEQ_0 :: 'Zero :<= n 
  LTEQ_Succ :: !(n :<= m) -> 'Succ n :<= 'Succ m

mapRoot :: n :<= m -> (Tree n a -> Tree n a) -> Tree m a -> Tree m a 
mapRoot p0 f0 t0 = restore (f0 root) where 
  (root, restore) = go p0 t0 

  go :: n :<= m -> Tree m a -> (Tree n a, Tree n a -> Tree m a) 
  go LTEQ_0 t = (Leaf, const t) 
  go (LTEQ_Succ p) (Branch a (l,r)) = 
    case (go p l, go p r) of 
      ((l', fl), (r', fr)) -> 
        ( Branch a (l', r')
        , \(Branch a1 (l1, r1)) -> Branch a1 (fl l1, fr r1)
        )
```

Note that `go` returns a pair - the root tree, and a function taking the processed root and returning the result. This makes it explicit (to the programmar and runtime!) that the resulting `Tree n a` does not depend on the input `Tree n a`.

Also, I've replaced your class with a GADT just for brevity.

Comment: I like this better than the hack I figured out to lazy match my GADT with `swapRoot (Branch a (l,r)) t = ... where ~(a',(l',r')) = (\(Branch a p) -> (a,p)) t` since the lack of dependence is now explicit.

Comment: The `case` here looks too strict. I think it leads to two passes (one explicit; one implicit).

Comment: @dfeuer I agree the case is strict - but wouldn't that be desired in this case? Due to `go` being strict, it must compute both the root tree and the function recomputing the final result from the transformed tree at once, meaning it must make only one pass. Perhaps I've misunderstood something.

Comment: @user2407038, I actually think the OP's original code is probably about the best possible for this exact function and this exact type. When passed a sufficiently lazy function (e.g., application of `fmap`), it only does one actual pass. I don't see how yours will perform any better with a non-lazy function, and I think it will be rather worse with a lazy one. I guess I could be missing something, though. It seems yours performs one pass over the tree, and then a second rebuilding pass after that is entirely complete. The original code interleaves these nicely.

Comment: dfeuer: Another advantage of user2407038's approach over my original is that I can also adapt it to [map all the subtrees of depth `n` that share a leaf layer with the original tree](http://lpaste.net/156726#line71).

Comment: @rampion, if you're referring to your `mapLeaf`, that's much closer to a traditional lens, and I think it's much better written directly, like this: http://lpaste.net/8472576886969466880 (with `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled).